# Docker-compose update port mapping of running containers

Tags: linux, docker

Running Docker Compose File in which port instruction makes elasticsearch to listen on port 9200 on all interfaces.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch_1
    image: elasticsearch:7.1.1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - elastic_network
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/
```

Updated Docker File to make elasticsearch to listen only on localhost:9200.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch_1
    image: elasticsearch:7.1.1
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9200:9200"
    networks:
      - elastic_network
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/elasticsearch/
```

How can i have the updated docker-compose file be executed for already running service of elasticsearch.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
4832a2df50e1        elasticsearch:7.1.1                      "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   6 days ago          Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elasticsearch_1
```

Comment: `docker-compose restart elasticsearch_1`?

Comment: doesn't change. **4832a2df50e1        elasticsearch:7.1.1                      "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   7 days ago          Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elasticsearch_1**

Comment: stop,, remove, start the container with docker-compose, then; cannot think of any other way